# OSGI Service components With same interface

Tags: osgi, equinox, declarative-services

I need to create service components with same interface. That mean i have different implementations for same interface. I tried to create two Components with same interface either one only active.

i am using equinox declarative. Do you have any better design to solve this problem? please find my configuration below.

**Component1.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="comp1">
   <implementation class="com.demo.impl.CompOneImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="com.demo.IComponent"/>
   </service>
 </scr:component>
```

**Component2.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="comp2">
   <implementation class="com.demo.impl.CompTwoImpl"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="com.demo.IComponent"/>
   </service>
 </scr:component>
```

**Accessing component from consumer**

***Consume component***

**comp1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="consumeComp1">
   <implementation class="com.demo.service.ConsumeCompOne"/>
   <reference bind="setComp" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.demo.IComponent" name="comp1" policy="static" unbind="unsetComp"/>
</scr:component>
```

**comp2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="consumeComp2">
   <implementation class="com.demo.service.ConsumeCompTwo"/>
   <reference bind="setComp" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.demo.IComponent" name="comp2" policy="static" unbind="unsetComp"/>
</scr:component>
```

when i try to access comp1 and comp2 respectively through ConsumeCompOne and ConsumeCompTwo class i am always getting same component for both, either comp1 or comp2. Please help me to solve this.

Thankyou in advance

gopy

Answer (score 1):

DS is working correctly, so there is nothing to solve here.

As you said, both consumer components get provided with an instance of the `IComponent` service, which is exactly what they are requesting as references.

Comment: What do you mean? Then my implementation should work right? i created ConsumeCompOne instance and accessing but it is return wrong some time.

Comment: You said that it's been provided with an instance of the component. So why is it wrong?

Comment: I printed both consumer adapter it is printing same implementation class such as com.demo.impl.CompOneImpl@14e98c44 and com.demo.impl.CompOneImpl@14e98c44 , I wonder how both instance pointing same implementation? Am i doing any wrong in configurations?

Comment: Yes, but why is it wrong for them both to point to the same implementation? They are consumers of a service, why do they care which implementation is provided? If the consumers depend on a specific implementation class then they are no longer decoupled, and there is no point using services.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to select a specific instance of a service then publish it with properties to identitfy it. On the client you can then use an OSGi service filter to select the one that matches e.g. a special key/value combination.

Comment: Do you have any sample code with declarative  to access via properties? it would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `target` attribute on the `reference` element to select the specific service to bind.

**comp1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="consumeComp1">
   <implementation class="com.demo.service.ConsumeCompOne"/>
   <reference bind="setComp" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.demo.IComponent" name="comp1" policy="static" unbind="unsetComp"
     target="(component.name=comp1)"/>
</scr:component>
```

**comp2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="consumeComp2">
   <implementation class="com.demo.service.ConsumeCompTwo"/>
   <reference bind="setComp" cardinality="1..1" interface="com.demo.IComponent" name="comp2" policy="static" unbind="unsetComp"
     target="(component.name=comp2)"/>
</scr:component>
```

Comment: BJ, my fear is the questioner hasn't learned much here about the benefits of decoupling via services... this was the reason for the line of questioning I took in my response. Oh well.